# Cordova device-orientation error on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, heading

I'm getting the following error from Xcode when trying to access the compass heading:

(void)getHeading:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command **EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1)**

Any idea on what is causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research here and there, I've found out that the error occurs on devices with architecture arm64 and it has been solved in the new release of cordova 3.5.

Download the new cordova release and update the project for iOS platform and it's all magically solved.